# Bash script using rc.status executing twice on newer SLES

Tags: bash, sles

I have the strange phenomenon that a long-standing admin script started running more or less twice when we moved from SLES 11 to SLES 12 (SuSE Enterprise Linux). I could track this down to being related to `/etc/rc.status` with a minimal example `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Sourcing rc.status
. /etc/rc.status
echo End of script
```

When this is run with `status` as parameter (a common use-case for my script)...

```
./test.sh status
```

...I observe this output:

```
Sourcing rc.status
Sourcing rc.status
End of script
End of script
```

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's been some poettering in the SLES `/etc/rc.status` file:

```
user@host:~> diff rc.status.sles11 /etc/rc.status
34a35,92
> # Check if the service is used under systemd but not started with
> if test -z "$SYSTEMD_NO_WRAP" && /usr/bin/mountpoint -q /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd; then
>     if test $PPID -ne 1 -a $# -eq 1 ; then
>       _rc_base=
...
```

So the solution is to set `SYSTEMD_NO_WRAP` before sourcing `/etc/rc.status`.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Sourcing rc.status
SYSTEMD_NO_WRAP=1
. /etc/rc.status
echo End of script
```

This gives the expected behaviour:

```
Sourcing rc.status
End of script
```